# Inserting a transparent logo to the ggplot2 background

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add a transparent image\logo to ggplot background.

I tried the below method.

```
 m <- readPNG(".\\Input\\Logo.png", FALSE)

 w <- matrix(rgb(m[,,1],m[,,2],m[,,3], m[,,4] * 0.2), nrow=dim(m)[1])

 qplot(1:10, rnorm(10), geom = "blank") +
 annotation_custom(xmin=-Inf, ymin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymax=Inf,    
 rasterGrob(w)) + geom_point()
```

but I am getting an error: Error in m[, , 4] : subscript out of bounds.

Thanks you for the support on this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have `.\\Input\\Logo.png` However, try this:

```
library(png)
m <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
w <- matrix(rgb(m[,,1],m[,,2],m[,,3], m[,,4] * 0.2), nrow=dim(m)[1])
qplot(1:10, rnorm(10), geom = "blank") +
  annotation_custom(xmin=-Inf, ymin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymax=Inf,    
                    rasterGrob(w)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: I am not geting the error when I use the Rlogo.png but I am getting an error while using the logo I need. The image dimensions are 223 * 92 pixels. Is it because of the size logo

Comment: Maybe you got a PNG of type RGB (3 color channels) instead of type RGBA (3 color channels + 1 alpha channel)? Providing the real image to create a reproducible example would be a good idea, don't you think? :->

Comment: Try `w <- abind::abind(m, matrix(0.2, ncol = ncol(m[,,3]), nrow = nrow(m[,,3])))` - `0.2` is your alpha/transparency value. There's probably a more elegant way to add the fourth dimension to your image array... But I guess that would make another question.

Comment: I was not able to load the PNG image hence could not post it here.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472833/inserting-a-transparent-logo-to-the-ggplot2-background/69784272#comment47110515_29472966) of @lukeA
`w <- abind::abind(m, matrix(0.2, ncol = ncol(m[,,3]), nrow = nrow(m[,,3]))) - 0.2` worked for me.